# Confused by "but" phrase in this sentence

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I'm translating a product leaflet into my native language, and have a problem with the following sentence:

"ABC's compact Probe-65 is an excellent choice when your application calls for turbidity monitoring, **but** only a few additional sensors."

I'm afraid I don't fully understand a meaning of `but` phrase in this context. Could anyone clarify it for me? Any help will be appreciated.
Regards,

Comment: I think there's a word (or more) missing from the "but...sensors" part.

Comment: I think it's trying to say: *ABC's compact Probe-65 is an excellent turbidity monitoring solution when your application calls for only a few sensors.* That is, the Probe-65 product is a turbidity monitoring sensor; buy a few.

Comment: I agree with KillingTime, this is poorly written.  It should be written "ABC's compact Probe-65 is an excellent choice when your application calls for turbidity monitoring, but only if a few additional sensors are used with it." . . . or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

"but" effectively means "and" here, like saying:

"ABC's compact Probe-65 is an excellent choice when your application calls for turbidity monitoring, **and** only a few additional sensors."

"But" generally tells us that something unexpected is happening, or something that contrasts with what we were told earlier.  "He normally walks to work but that day he got the bus" for example.

The "but" draws attention to the fact that there's an unexpectedly small number of additional sensors (which presumably makes it cheaper or something) - there's an implication that if you want turbidity monitoring you would normally have to have a *lot* of additional sensors, so the 'but' draws the reader's attention to the fact that there are less additional sensors than you would expect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.